# How can I play the CnC mod 'Rise of the Reds' multiplayer?

Tags: command-and-conquer-zero-hour

I have game *Command & Conquer: Generals - Zero Hour*, and I have installed the mod *'Rise of the Reds 1.86'* for it.

Does anyone have idea how I could play it multiplayer with my friends, whether with Game Ranger or on some other way?

Answer (score 2):

Ever since the official support through GameSpy disappeared [when GameSpy shut down in July 2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GameSpy#Shutdown), multiplayer for the post-RA2 C&C games is provided by the community servers of [the CnC-Online project](https://cnc-online.net/). Check out their [Setup](https://cnc-online.net/setup/) page for more info on how to get it running.

Playing mods on their system should not be a problem, according to their [FAQ](https://cnc-online.net/faq/).